# flink on k8s session mode always restarts the jobmanager

Tags: java, apache-flink

In the flink on k8s session mode I deployed, the submitted task jobmanager always restarts, resulting in the task cannot be executed, but it can run normally in idea.

I don't know what the problem is and I can't find any useful error information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.